# Didn't I supply the dialect?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js, dialect

I'm trying to create a database with Sequelize.  I keep getting this error.

> Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
> at new Sequelize

Here's my "new Sequelize" constructor (or whatever you call it):

```
    var sequelize = new Sequelize("seqGenZoo_db", "root", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

Looks like the dialect is provided.  What's the deal?  I've installed the mysql and mysql2 nmp packages, if that means anything.

Comment: there is a password missing after root

Comment: Hmmm yeah, I got rid of that because it was causing problems, namely error 1045.

Comment: You can"t get rid of the password try to solve the problem with the 1045 first

Answer (score 1):

Error 1045 indeed means you have incorrect user/password pair. And according to the official [documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-constructor-constructor) you should indicate `database`, `username`, `password` and `options` parameters:

```js
public constructor(database: string, username: string, password: string, options: Object)
```